# Deleting a question with an active bounty, but no answers

Tags: discussion

I've got a current question, which even with a active bounty hasn't drawn any answers or even comments pointing towards possible answers.

I take full responsibility for this.  Others on the site have pointed out that I tend to questions which have far too much description or background.  They  also fall more into applied mathematics.  As such they may simply not fit the rhythm and spirit of the site.

While, I'd love to get answers here, I may have more success breaking up the question and spreading pieces of it out to other sites.

In such a situation is it appropriate and fair for me to delete the question while it still has an active bounty?

---

I just learned that the software doesn't permit deleting a question with an open bounty.  As I've described in a comment, I think it best to delete the question, farm out pieces to more appropriate venues, then come back with a more focused question if I need more mathematical insight to wrap up the problem.

Can one appeal to moderators to have the question deleted in this case?
Where/how would I do so?

My intent here really goes to wanting to respect the site and its community and better call on its resources.

Please advise.

Comment: Deleting th question would make you lose the bounty. I think in this special case, I would suggest isolating a main problem and editing the question to reduce it to this problem.

Comment: You can post a piece on another site, and refer here for the full picture, if someone wants to see it (some users might).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker - The bounty goes in any case;-)  I'm thinking it best to delete the question, farm out parts of it on other sites, than come back with a very focused question here if I need to synthesize or clarify the mathematical insight.  Thanks for the thoughts.  I really just want to do the right thing to respect the site and the community.